# Editing links URLs in a Office 365 Public Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, office-365

I have a hard time changing the URL addresses of my pages in my public site created in Office 365.

Not only is the "Navigation" link missing in my Site Settings (which i suppose is due to the Publishing Feature not being activated, but then again I can't activate it because there's no link in Site Settings for that either) but editing links via the "Edit Links" option provides a greyed-out textbox with the URL. So obviously can't edit it there either. I am now out of ideas how to structure my URLs properly.

Does anybody know why the textbox is greyed out or has a better way of editing my links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Page -> Edit Properties -> Edit SEO Properties and the subtab "Term Name". In there you'll find "Edit friendly URL properties".

Hopefully this saved you some time

Comment: I can't find this setting anywhere. We're on the 2013 version of SharePoint

Comment: @MatthewSteeples you need to click on Page -> Edit Properties (expand a submenu) -> Edit SEO Properties -> Term name, Edit term properties to customize the friendly URL segment used for this page. (at the top of the edit form)

Comment: There's no field labelled Term name on the Edit SEO Properties Page. I have Name, Title, Browser Title, Meta Description, Keywords and Exclude from internet searches only

Comment: How did you create the page? I find that if I create it designer for example then the field is missing, however if I use the "gear" menu and click on "Add Page" then it's there! Imagine the fun I had trying to find that out for myself.

Comment: No Term name here either to fix this - likely as a result of changing name of page (within O365 itself, SP Designer says its a higher version yet won't update itself... sigh, endless issues again). It's 2015 now. So basic, so clunky - MS can't even pull off a CMS anymore, no wonder they've dropped Public Sites. Shame, why bother promoting O365 Sites?